# Does anyone know how to create a table of contents in R Markdown like the one in the kableExtra documentation?

Tags: r, r-markdown, documentation, tableofcontents

I was looking at the documentation for the kableExtra package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#column__row_specification) and love the table of contents that's being used here.

The default way, to add in the table of contents in the header options creates a more rigid TOC at the top of the page. This is shown with the following parameters in the document header -

```
title: "Planets"
author: "Manoj Kumar"
date: "March 3, 2016"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true # table of content true
    toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ## and ###)
    number_sections: true  ## if you want number sections at each table header
    theme: united  # many options for theme, this one is my favorite.
    highlight: tango  # specifies the syntax highlighting style
```

Does anyone know how to replicate the example on the kableExtra documentation?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Perhaps `toc_float: true`? Results in a floating toc on the left of the body. BTW: You find the source rmd on github: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/blob/master/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.Rmd

Comment: Nice, that was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks Stefan! Also, good to see the source .rmd as well